# declare type PromiseConstructorLike, new Promise in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, promise, visual-studio-code

I'm editing TypeScript files, and `Promise` isn't found by the TypeScript compiler or in Visual Studio Code. Instead `PromiseConstructorLike, PromiseLike<T>` are found as shown in [lib.d.ts](http://file://C:%5CProgram%20Files%20(x86)%5CMicrosoft%20VS%20Code%5Cresources%5Capp%5Cextensions%5Ctypescript%5Cserver%5Ctypescript%5Clib%5Clib.d.ts) or [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts) below.

```
declare type PromiseConstructorLike = new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void)
=> void) => PromiseLike<T>;

interface PromiseLike<T> {
    /**
    * Attaches callbacks for the resolution and/or rejection of the Promise.
    * @param onfulfilled The callback to execute when the Promise is resolved.
    * @param onrejected The callback to execute when the Promise is rejected.
    * @returns A Promise for the completion of which ever callback is executed.
    */
    then<TResult>(onfulfilled?: (value: T) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>, onrejected?: (reason: any) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>): PromiseLike<TResult>;
    then<TResult>(onfulfilled?: (value: T) => TResult | PromiseLike<TResult>,
```

I tried placing the following in my TypeScript file

```
var Promise : PromiseConstructorLike;
...

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    ...
    return value;

}).then(value => {
    ...
});
```

which compiles, however I get a runtime error

```
TypeError: Promise is not a constructor
```

What is the correct syntax or code to accomplish a `new Promise(` as shown above?

Comment: `PromiseConstructorLike` is the type that describes the `Promise` constructor; not the constructor itself.

Comment: Could it be that it infers the value of `Promise` to be `undefined`? Does it know that the global `Promise` variable is already initialised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare var Promise : PromiseConstructorLike;
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Since the codec compiled, this doesn't seem like an issue with the type declarations. You need to make your you actually have Promise available in your JS runtime. This can be achieved by using a promise polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

With one extra line

```
declare var Promise : PromiseConstructorLike;
```

you can use Promises in Typescript like this:

```
let myPromise= new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{...});
```